# Null when connect GraphQL with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, graphql

I connect GraphQL with MongoDB but result is `null`. Help me !

index.js file:

```
const { graphql } = require('graphql');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const assert = require('assert');
const readline = require('readline');

const mySchema = require('./schema/main.js');
const rli = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});
const MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test';

MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB server');
    rli.question('Client Request: ', inputQuery => {
        graphql(mySchema, inputQuery, {}, { db }).then(result => {
            console.log('Server Answer: ', result.data);
            db.close(() => rli.close());
        });
    });
});
```

main.js file:

```
const {
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLInt
} = require('graphql');

const queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQuery',
    fields: {
        usersCount: {
            type: GraphQLInt,
            resolve: (_, args, { db }) => db.collection('users').count()
        }
    }
});

const mySchema = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: queryType
});

module.exports = mySchema;
```

And this is result:

```
Connected to MongoDB server
Client Request: { usersCount }
Server Answer:  { usersCount: null }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i could understand the `db` object you get from `MongoClient` connect callback is not your `db` object but instead the `client` object so 
you should first call

```
const db = client.db
```

see [Connect to MongoDB](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#connect-to-mongodb)

this is something that you can find and fix easily if you can debug your code